# Why does the slant range become 0 for the given relation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, momentum, projectile

I was working with coefficient of restitution, and was met with this problem from my textbook. Since I found it pretty interesting, I decided to solve it symbolically.

[image]

I let $v_0, e, \theta$ be my given variables for which I had to express my solution with, and of course the gravitational constant $g$.

I eventually managed to show that the slant range $R = 2e\frac{v_0}{g}\tan\theta\sec\theta(\cos^2\theta - e\sin^2\theta)$ which after substituting the given variables in the problem, matches exactly with the result given in the answers at the back of the book.

I then wanted to analyze the result. For instance, we see that $R = 0$ for when $\tan^2\theta = 1/e$. Of course, $R$ would be $0$ if we would let $\theta$ be $0$, but what really happens in this case? Can anyone explain it for me?

Thank you.

Comment: For $\theta = 0$ there can be no collision.

Comment: Well, the only way to have zero range is if the ball bounces straight up and comes straight down again...

Comment: @DJohnM Yes, that I do understand, but how this this scenario relate to the relation of $\tan^2(\theta) = 1/e$?

Comment: @Dan I understand that, sorry if I made myself unclear. What I'm really asking for is why does $\tan^2(\theta) = 1/e$ give us a range R = 0?

Comment: The ball has a velocity parallel to the inclined surface which does not change during the collision;  it has a velocity normal to the inclined surface, which is reversed and reduced by e.  Find the horizontal component  of each, sum them, set the sum equal to zero and rearrange.

Comment: @DJohnM Thank you. I see what's happening now. :)

Answer (score 0):

To memorialize the comments:

The incoming velocity $v_0$ has two components **relative to the surface**:

(In the surface frame of reference, arbitrarily, up the slope is positive, into the slope is negative, and angles are positive as drawn).

the tangential component, which remains constant throughout the collision
$$(v_0)_T=v_0 \cos\theta $$and the normal velocity:$$(v_0)_N=-v_0 \sin\theta $$**After the collision**, the normal velocity is reversed (it bounces!) and reduced by a factor of $e$; **now** the normal velocity is:$$(v_0)_N=ev_0 \sin\theta $$

Switching back to true **horizontal and vertical** components and focusing on the horizontal components, adding them, and setting the resultant horizontal velocity equal to zero :$$
v_0 \cos\theta \times \sin (\theta)+(-ev_0 \sin\theta )\times \cos(\theta)-0$$
Rearranging;$$v_0 \cos\theta \times \sin (\theta)=ev_0 \sin(\theta )\times \cos(\theta)$$which reduces to:$$(\tan(\theta))^2 = 1/e$$